# MySQL :multiple select and join query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following schema :

```
Department (dept_id, dept_name)

Student (student_id, student_name, major, level, age)

Professor (prof_id, prof_name, dept_id)

Class (name, meets_at, room, prof_id)

Enrolled (student_id, class_name, semester)
```

I need to Find the names of students with level `SR` who are enrolled in a class
taught by professor who works in department `Computer Science`.

based on my relational algebra understanding my attempt was

```
SELECT s.student_name FROM ( SELECT d.dept_id FROM department as d WHERE d.dept_name = 'computer science' 

                        JOIN professor as p on d.dept_id = p.dept_id

                        JOIN class as c on p.prof_id = c.prof_id 
                        JOIN enrolled as e on c.name = e.class_name
                        JOIN student as s on s.student_id = e.student_id )
                        WHERE s.level = 'sr' ;
```

but when i try it out i get sql syntax error.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Subqueries need to have aliases in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT s.student_name 
FROM department d
JOIN professor p on d.dept_id = p.dept_id
JOIN class c on p.prof_id = c.prof_id 
JOIN enrolled e on c.name = e.class_name
JOIN student s on s.student_id = e.student_id 
WHERE s.level = 'sr' 
    AND d.dept_name = 'computer science'
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT s.student_name FROM (you have to mention table name) where s.level = 'sr' ;

without table name it will show error.